# How to run jobs longer than 24 hours on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, clockwork

How can we run background jobs that take longer than 24 hours on Heroku? Since every dyno is killed once a day it seems impossible, even if I have a dedicated worker dyno to handle it. Is writing my job in a way that it'll continue from where it stopped when was killed the only way?

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: Is it a continuous background "service"? Or does it really take over a day to complete?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to break that long job up into a number of small jobs that can be handled independently.  What exactly are you doing that takes more than 24 hours?

Comment: I have a script that rebuilds a table using data from dozens other tables.

Right... that's what I thought as well.